# node:internal/errors:496 ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err); ^ Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, authentication, jwt, backend, mern

```
node:internal/errors:496
    ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);
    ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module
server\controllers\authController.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:405:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:224:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:836:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1034:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:375:12)       
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:344:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:220:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  url: URL {},
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I'm building a mern stack app and I faced this problem. I reinstalled node and made sure all the dependensies are installed

Comment: seems it's complaining about `server/controllers/authController.js` ... perhaps you need to use `./server/controllers/authController.js` in your code